# How long would daytime and nightime be on a planet with a 26 hours rotational period?

Tags: science-based, space, geography, time, day-night

The basics about the planet in question: As the second planet in the star system, it's somewhat warmer than Earth is. The rotational period is 26 hours and the orbital period is 312 days which consequently corresponds to 288 local days. However, due to a highly eccentric orbit, seasons have varying lenghts and intensity on each corner of the planet. In the southern hemisphere, where intelligent life has emerged, summer lasts for 4 (Gregorian) months and winter lasts for 2,4 (Gregorian) months. The axial tilt is comparable to that of Earth (25 degrees) and let's say that the latitude of interest is 47° 29' 52.84" N.

To be honest, I'm not sure to which degree eccentricity influences the day and night cycle but the planet's rotation definitely does which is why I'm asking this question. I also know that the amount of sunlight an area receives depends on the latitude so I'm not even sure how much of an approximate answer can be given to this. Where I live, sunset is at about 20:45 on the summer solstice. I guess what I would really like to know is how long an average or the longest/shortest day would be on such a planet at the same latitude where I live (because that's my point of reference).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add it. Now it's in the question. I'll have a look at the link, though.

Comment: Unless you want to specify some differences in the orbital characteristics, why would everything not be 26/24 of what it is here on Earth?